# Flash Builder 4.7 and 4.0 possible?

Tags: apache-flex, installation, flash-builder, flashbuilder4

Hi I have a licensed Flash Builder 4.0 installed. Can I install 4.7 on the same pc? I need to test if the app can be compiled with Apache Flex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, simply install Flash Builder 4.7 to a different location.

Note that you can use later Flex versions in Flash Builder 4.0; follow the steps in the answer to [Use Flex 4.5 and 4.0 in Adobe Flash Builder 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991569/use-flex-4-5-and-4-0-in-adobe-flash-builder-4)